# Is it preferable to say $v$ is " image distance " than to say " image position " in spherical mirror formula?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

I was going through spherical mirror formula  $1/v + 1/u = 1/f$ where $u$, $v$ and $f$ are named as object distance, image distance and focal length respectively. But while using this equation we do put values with proper sign taking pole of mirror as origin. And what I know is distances are not negative. So in place of naming them as distances can we name them as positions like object position ,  image position and position of focus.

Comment: It sounds like you have the right idea. Don't get confused if the problem isn't posed with quite the right vocabulary.